# Show that the Weierstrass ℘-function takes any value in $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

In *Complex Analysis* by Freitag it is claimed that the Weierstrass ℘-function takes any value in $\mathbb{C}$ that is the map is $℘: \mathbb{C}-L \to \mathbb{C}$ is surjective. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $\wp$ misses $a\in\mathbb{C}$. Then, $1/(\wp-a)$ is now defined at $L\subset\mathbb{C}$, so we get a function $1/(\wp-a) : \mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ which is holomorphic but bounded (due to double-periodicity of $\wp$), so by Louiville it is constant (but it's obviously not!)